# "Parameter passing to function" or "Assigning values to Properties and then using them in function" is better choice?

Tags: c#, oop

While designing a class ( in c#, or any oop lang) i always get confused with shall i have property defined in a class and use it in methods of class , or it's good to simply have method parameters.

One problem i found in first way is that it creates dependancy (like , what if caller has forgotten to assign the value to the property etc..).

e.g. I am designing a class "myexcel" which does "export to cvs" , "Get XML" , "format excel and save"

Here shall i have "ExcelPath" as property of myexcel or shall i pass it as parameter to GetXml , export , format  methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties should define the state associated with object - the state information that qualifies say one instance from other instance. It does not make sense to store a temporal information that is valid for a single function invocation into the object state. In other words, if you make something a object property because its get used in some method then it would only make sense if the same property value is used across multiple invocation or the property get used in multiple methods.

So in your particular case, filePath should be a parameter for all save/export methods because from usage perspective, the object instance represent some data and save/export is a just a way to serialize it. The file path would be valid for that call only - it will likely to change over multiple invocations.

Comment: makes sense. Ok then what could be property of myexcel class ?

Comment: Depends on the implementation (and how are you modelling). For example, if there is no state involved - you can make it a static (helper) class. So GetXml/ExportToCSV would be static methods taking excel file path and destination path. OTH, if you are reading excel file into memory and then have methods that do some sort of manipulation (say `AddWorkSheet`) and/or allow to browse the information (`GetWorkSheets`) then it make sense to accept the excel path as constructor parameter and have a read-only property for the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a judgment call.  In your example, it depends on whether you want instances of your type to represent specific files in the file system.  If so, throw an invalid operation exception when Save is called but Path is invalid.  If not, require a path parameter for the Save method, and throw an invalid argument exception if the value is invalid.

More generally, properties should represent *state*, while method parameters should represent information that's needed by the method, but external to the object's state.

Comment: well, then i am not letting caller an oppotunity to know in advance. This may imply on the myexcel writer that the design is wrong.

Comment: The type's documentation typically describes the circumstances under which an invalid operation exception would be thrown.  In this case, you might implement a property or method that returns true when the object haas a valid path.  Something like HasValidPath, PathIsValid, or CanSave.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this small example.

You have a class `WashingMachine`. Its duty is to wash clothes.

```
 class WashingMachine
{

       public void WashClothes()
       {

       }

}
```

Now will you make `List<clothToWash> listOfCloth` a property or `parameter` to `WashClothes`?

It will be clear if it is made as parameter to `WashClothes` rather than Property, because it does not define the ***`state`*** of the object.

In addition to that, Properties should be cheap, should not throw exceptions while assigning values.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "It will be clear.." is relative here. For me making properties can be more clear as How heavy is my machine can be a state and it will be determined from this number of clothes property.

Comment: I think you should make it as a function at that time. As I have mentioned, properties should be cheap to calculate.

Comment: And I also agree, it is relative.

Comment: :) "properties should be cheap to calculate"  Again, This "cheap" is relative.